# Laravel: How do I raise a 404 error instead of a 50X error when ID for resource is non-integer

Tags: laravel

I created a simple crud in Laravel, but I'm having a problem:

I am using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::resource method, this is my routes/web.php:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::get('dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'dashboard'])
    ->middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->name('dashboard');

Route::resource('notes', App\Http\Controllers\NoteController::class)
    ->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

app/Http/Controllers/NoteController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class NoteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->q) {
            return Inertia::render('Notes/Index', [
                'notes' => Note::where('title', 'ilike', "%$request->q%")->get(),
            ]);
        }
        return Inertia::render('Notes/Index', [
            'notes' => Note::all()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Notes/Create', [
            'note' => new Note()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $note = Note::create($request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]));

        return redirect()->route('notes.show', $note)->with('success', 'Nota creada');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Note $note)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Notes/Show', compact('note'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Note $note)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Notes/Edit', compact('note'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Note $note)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]);

        $note->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('notes.show', $note)->with('success', 'Nota actualizada');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Note $note)
    {
        $note->delete();

        return redirect()->route('notes.index')->with('success', 'Nota eliminada');
    }
}
```

When I go to /notes/a where 'a' is supposed to be the index of the note I want to see, I get a 500 error:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "a"
```

`select * from "notes" where "id" = a limit 1`

At this point, none of my code has yet run. How can I catch this error to raise a 404 error instead?

Comment: Can you show more on the route's implementation?

Comment: please add your controller code to view the edit blade in your question

Comment: @AaronT, I edited my question to include web.php content. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the built-in resource controller, the following URIs, among others,  will have been created and model binding happens. If the parameter doesn't fit the id's type it will error out.

```
GET /notes/{note}
GET /notes/{note}/edit
```

I have not found a way to modify the request validation when model binding happens. If you wish to customise the behaviour, you can do so by leaving the `show` and `edit` functions out of the route resource declaration and writing custom endpoints listed above.

routes/web.php

```php
Route::resource('notes', NoteController::class)->except([
    'show', 'edit'
]);

Route::get('/notes/{note}', [
    'as' => 'notes.show',
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\NoteController@show',
]);
```

app/Http/Controllers/NoteController.php

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $noteId = $request->note;
        ...
    }
```

You can perform the validation by switching `Request` to a custom request which inherits `FormRequest`.

More information can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 0):

Route model binding has worked as you expect forever on MySQL/MariaDB but [does not on Postgres](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26239). Based on Taylor's [comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26239#issuecomment-618455319) in the issue, they don't seem interested in fixing it. So the solution is something like this:

```php
Route::resource('users', UserController::class)->whereNumber('user');
Route::resource('notes', NoteController::class)->whereNumber('note');
```

etc.

An updated and optimized route file would look like this:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\NoteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PageController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function (Router $router) {
    $router->get('dashboard', [PageController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    $router->resource('notes', NoteController::class)->whereNumber('note');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use firstOrFail() or findOrFail example code below

```
public function find(Request $request){
    return Note::findOrFail($request->id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use abort(404) which abort your code if no data found.

```
public function findNote($id)
{
    $note = Note::find($id)
    
    if($note == null)
    {
    abort(404);
    }
}
```